# How to check if an NSWindow is open

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, appkit

I have an `NSWindow` which can be closed and reopened (I've called `[setReleasedWhenClosed: NO]`). How do I check if it is open or closed programmatically?

I've read the doc and Googled but can't see a sane way to do this. `[isVisible]` is deprecated. `[occlusionState]` isn't what I'm after. I've worked around it using notifications, but I can't believe there isn't some property or method on `NSWindow` to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make make of use of screen property of NSWindow. If the window in offscreen it will return nil. Please check https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/screen

Comment: Tested this without success—seems that the `screen` property is never `nil` as soon as I instantiate the windows controller.

Answer (score 12):

`-[NSWindow isVisible]` is not really deprecated.

For the 10.10 SDK, Apple went through and converted a bunch of informal properties to declared properties. An informal property is one for which there are just accessors declared, possibly just a getter method. A declared property uses `@property`.

As a consequence, they removed something like:

```
- (BOOL) isVisible;
```

and added:

```
@property (getter=isVisible, readonly) BOOL visible;
```

Note that both still imply the existence of an `-isVisible` getter with `BOOL` return type.

The tools they use to generate the documentation from the changes to their headers caused the documentation to claim that `-isVisible` is deprecated, but that's just wrong.

Note, though, that `-isVisible` reports false for a window which is minimized or which is "open" but in a hidden app.

Comment: I don't see this in the documentation for NSWindow.

Comment: You don't see what? The `visible` property? Yes, I know. What I'm telling you is that documentation is buggy. Look at the `NSWindow` class declaration (e.g. Command-click on `NSWindow` in your code). Or just write code which uses the `visible` property and/or the `-isVisible` method and observe that the compiler doesn't emit any deprecation warnings (or any other warnings).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough (though disappointing! ;) description. I've not accepted this as the answer because Sheen's suggestion is closer to what I wanted - but I wish I could pick two answers in this case!