# Check if NSMenuItem is enabled

Tags: macos, cocoa

Up until OS X 10.9, there was a method to check whether a menu item was enabled or not.

From the API documentation of NSMenuItem:

```
- isEnabled Available in OS X v10.0 through OS X v10.9
```

Is it possible on OS X 10.10 to somehow determine if a NSMenuItem currently shown in the menu bar is enabled?

Comment: there exists still a property `enabled` which returns a bool value. Somehow the documentation by Apple is ambiguous regarding that property.

Comment: See the answer to this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253375/how-to-check-if-an-nswindow-is-open/29256230#29256230

Comment: Thx, using the enabled property worked. Apparently, using the selector `isEnabled` still works. Although I don't really understand the documentation as it says in the `setEnabled` section: `@property(getter=isEnabled) BOOL enabled` but lists `isEnabled` as deprecated...